Extract text from table in a image with
i want to extract data from this table in this image, i use cv2 and
pytesseract but I don't get reliable results. This is my code and my image.

import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Load the image using OpenCV
    img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
    # Apply thresholding (binarization)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    
    # Invert the image colors
    inverted_img = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
    
    # Convert the thresholded and inverted image back to PIL image format
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(inverted_img)
    
    return pil_img

def image_to_text(path):
    # Path to your Tesseract executable
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    
    # Preprocess the image
    img = preprocess_image(path)
    
    # Perform OCR using Tesseract
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 4 --oem 2 ', lang='rus')
    
    return text


print(image_to_text('concatenated_image3.jpg'))


Your text is too small.
